# How do I rollback the appcfg in Google App Engine's Python SDK?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appcfg

I was attempting to publish code for my website the other day and then I was greeted with this:

```
2016-03-14 01:18:30 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\Bryce/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update', 'C:\\Users\\Bryce\\Desktop\\ShaolinP']"
01:19 AM Application: shaolinpretzels; version: 2
01:19 AM Host: appengine.google.com
01:19 AM 
Starting update of app: shaolinpretzels, version: 2
01:19 AM Getting current resource limits.
01:23 AM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user classsicb is already in progress for app: s~shaolinpretzels, version: 2. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
--- end server output ---
2016-03-14 01:29:21 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

I have **NO EXPERIENCE in programming in Python**, I used a template in order to publish the website. If someone could detail how to rollback the appcfg, for *someone who's never worked with Python*, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because an initial update might have stalled or something. So you need to rollback like the error message points out.

In your specific case, you can open the **command prompt**(<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `cmd` then <kbd>enter</kbd>) and run the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py rollback C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop\ShaolinP
```

Comment: Thank you; I had to put "Program Files (x86)" in double quotes, but the rest of the code was functional and solved my problem.